# Pyspark: How to aggregate data for all the elements in a list in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am storing all the string fields in a list object. Then currently i am passing each field inside the for loop to calculate the aggregated count.

I am looking for a way to get the aggregated count at once for all the string columns. Please help.

Sample data:

Dataframe(Input_Data) is having these records

```
NoOfSegments,SegmentID,Country
3,2,Bangalore
3,2,Bangalore
3,3,Delhi
3,2,Delhi
3,3,Delhi
3,1,Pune
3,3,Bangalore
3,1,Pune
3,1,Delhi
3,3,Bangalore
3,1,Delhi
3,3,Bangalore
3,3,Pune
3,2,Delhi
3,3,Pune
3,2,Pune
3,2,Pune
3,3,Pune
3,1,Bangalore
3,1,Bangalore
```

MY code:

```
        input_data.createOrReplaceTempView('input_data')

        sub="string"
        category_columns = [name for name, data_type in input_data.dtypes
                                if sub in data_type]
        df_final_schema = StructType([StructField("Country", StringType())
                           , StructField("SegmentID", IntegerType())
                           , StructField("total_cnt", IntegerType())
                        ])
        df_final=spark.createDataFrame([],df_final_schema)

        for cat_col in category_columns:
            query="SELECT {d_name} as Country,SegmentID ,(count(*) over(partition by {d_name},SegmentID)/ count(*) over(partition by NoOfSegments))*100 as total_cnt  from input_temp order by {d_name},SegmentID".format(d_name=cat_col)
            new_df=hc.sql(query)
            df_final = df_final.union(new_df)
```

Result:

[image]

Is there any way I can pass all the string columns and calculate the above result at once a data frame?

Comment: It seems you need a `groupBy` for that. Have you considered something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826502/pyspark-dataframe-group-by-filtering ?

Comment: Yes, oK. Let me try that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following using `groupBy` (or `groupby`) :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

total = df.select(F.sum("NoOfSegments")).take(1)[0][0]
df \
  .groupBy("SegmentID", "Country") \
  .agg(F.sum('NoOfSegments').alias('sums'))\
  .withColumn('total_cnt', 100 * F.col('sums')/ F.lit(total)) \
  .select('country', 'SegmentID', 'total_cnt') \
  .sort('country', 'SegmentID').show()
# +---------+---------+---------+
# |  Country|SegmentID|total_cnt|
# +---------+---------+---------+
# |Bangalore|        1|     10.0|
# |Bangalore|        2|     10.0|
# |Bangalore|        3|     15.0|
# |    Delhi|        1|     10.0|
# |    Delhi|        2|     10.0|
# |    Delhi|        3|     10.0|
# |     Pune|        1|     10.0|
# |     Pune|        2|     10.0|
# |     Pune|        3|     15.0|
# +---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful